# Download File Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to save a file so that it can be downloaded by a user.  When I use

```
string  path = "~/App_data";
Server.GetPath(path)
```

I get a location can't be found.  It's trying to find the absolute path not the virtual path correct?  Why?

I'm trying to save here so it can be downloaded.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this question is explicitly off topic, from the close reasons: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* Additionally this really isn't a discussion forum, we provide specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: Try Server.MapPath instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx